# C# XNA4.0 keyboardstate error

Tags: c#, xna, keyboard, state

I am trying to move a sprite but it won't even let me debug.
When i try to debug i get the following error:

> **Error 1 The name 'keys' does not exist in the current context**

What am i doing wrong? or is it something else? According to multiple sources this is one of the ways to make a sprite move.

I've never been able to use keyboard input to move something or make something happen for some reason. Kinda lost here :(

Here's the code:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    Texture2D myTexture;
    Vector2 spritePosition = Vector2.Zero;
    Vector2 spriteSpeed = new Vector2(50.0f, 50.0f);
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    KeyboardState keystate;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("sprite");
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        keystate = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (keystate.IsKeyDown(keys.right))
            spritePosition.X += spriteSpeed.X;
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, spritePosition, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: In future posts, please keep in mind that a block of text is very hard to read, paragraphs are good! :) Also, your code had a *ton* of unnecessary whitespace resulting in lots of extra scrolling for us question readers. I've fixed it all, but these are good things to keep in mind when posting in the future.

Comment: In your Update, specifically in the IsKeyDown check, you're using keys but you never define it. IIRC, XNA provides the Keys enum. Capitalize the K.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil, just checked MSDN, it is capital K "Keys", and that should fix his problem.

Comment: Just checked myself too, going to make the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the actual XNA `Keys` enumeration ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keys.aspx)):

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    keystate = Keyboard.GetState();

    if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        spritePosition.X += spriteSpeed.X;
}
```

Remember, C# is case sensitive!

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, i totally didn't think about that! it works now :)